# dynamic DIV and jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am creating DIVs with dynamic IDs that I am trying to submit to a database to retrieve data. I think I should use "this" but I am not an experienced coder. While I do get the concept of "this" and don't know how to use it.

```
for (var i in data.results) 
  {
  document.getElementById("list-canvas").innerHTML += "<div id='list_element" + 
  data.results[i].id + "'>" +
  "<div id='list_image'>" +
    "<div id='actual_image'>" + data.results[i].feature_image +
    "</div>" +
  "</div>" +
"</div>";

       $(document).on('click', "#list_element"+data.results[i].id, function()
           {
           $.post('sql_p.php', {id : data.results[i].id }, function(data)
              {
              $("#left_2").hide();$("#left_3").show();
              document.getElementById("left_3").innerHTML = data;
              });
           });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` will refer to the object on which a method is being invoked. For eg: take the click function in your code. You are binding the click function to the `#list_element+data.results[i].id`. In this function you can use the `$(this)` to say add a new class like `$(this).addClass()` or `$(this).hide()` something like this. Calling $(this) ends up in the part of the jQuery constructor that takes care of a supplied DOMElement. You can check out [this](http://coding.abel.nu/2013/04/this-and-this-in-jquery-callbacks/) article.

Comment: I read through your comment and the link and trying different things. The problem in my code is here: "id : data.results[i].id". How would you replace "data.results[i].id" using "this"? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `data.results.id` by `$(this)[0].id`